# import javax.imageio.ImageIO; Has Error

Tags: java, android, swing, import, javax.imageio

I have searched high and low and have found no answer, when I try to do

`import javax.imageio.ImageIO;`

It says "Cannot resolve symbol imageio". This is an almost complete android app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was mentioned, the `ImageIO` class is not available on Android. You can do image decoding in Android using the [`BitmapFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're trying to achieve, but you probably want to use the Bitmap / BitmapFactory to solve your problem.